$Cov(\max(x, 0), \min(x, 0))$ where $x \sim N(0, 1)$
I've been stuck on this problem.
Let $y \sim \max(x, 0) \quad z \sim \min(x, 0)$
$$Cov(y, z) = E[z \cdot y] - E[y]\cdot E[z]$$
It's clear that $E[z \cdot y] = 0$, but what is $E[y]\cdot E[z]$? Is there a way of solving this without integration?

Are you mean $y \sim \max(x, 0)$  as a function ?

I doubt it can be done without integration, as it's equivalent to knowing the PDF's normalisation constant.

You can represent $$max (x,0)=\frac {x+|x|}{2}$$and $$min(x,0)=\frac {x-|x|}{2}$$

$$E[Max(X,0) + Min(X,0)] = E[X+0]=E[X]=0$$
Let $f(x)$ be the density of the standard normal distribution.
Let $u=-x^2/2, \frac{du}{dx}=-x$
\begin{align}
E[max(X,0)] &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \max(x,0)f(x)\, dx \\
&=\int_0^\infty x f(x)\, dx\\
&= \int_0^\infty x \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2} \, dx\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty xe^{-x^2/2} \, dx \\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^{-\infty} -e^{u} \, du \\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{u} \, du \\\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}
\end{align}
I will leave the rest to you.

Verification of result: The following code would give a value that is similar to $\frac1{2\pi}$.
import numpy as np

# Set the random seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(42)

# Number of samples
num_samples = 10000

# Generate samples from a standard normal distribution
X = np.random.normal(size=num_samples)

# Compute max(X, 0) and min(X, 0)
Y = np.maximum(X, 0)
Z = np.minimum(X, 0)

# Estimate the covariance between Y and Z
covariance = np.cov(Y, Z)[0, 1]

print("Covariance between max(X, 0) and min(X, 0):", covariance)
print(1/(2*np.pi))


If my math and intuition is correct, $\min(x, 0)$ is just $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$? So the covariance is $\frac{1}{2\pi}$? It seems odd to me that the covariance would be positive.

yes, the expectation of $\min(X,0)$ is just $-\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}$.

It should be positive. when $Y$ is positive, $Z$ is $0$, When $Y$ is $0$, $Z$ is negative. Y increases as $Z$ increases.
